# Elliptic Curve 256 public key in readable (DER?) format in .NET Core

Tags: authentication, .net-core, cryptography, jwt

I have .NET core application and EC 256 public key as point of a curve (x and y) in the following format

```
public class ECDsaPublicKey
{
    public byte[] X { get; set; }
    public byte[] Y { get; set; }
    public string Algorithm => SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256; // "ES256"

}
```

I need to use it on external services to verify JWT signature (https://jwt.io/)

**How can I get it to "service-readable" (DER base64-encoded?) format?** Is there easy way to do this?

So that I can paste it to the "Public Key" input field on that site and get "Valid Signature"

Example JWT token: `eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1laWRlbnRpZmllciI6InNvbWVVc2VyIiwiUm9sZSI6IlJlYWRlciIsIkFjY2VzcyI6IioiLCJleHAiOjE1Njg2MzcxODcsImlzcyI6Imlzc3VlciIsImF1ZCI6ImF1ZGllbmNlIn0.pJBPAKxXUl-wU3HCV-UPPpyuyfNJJXvRXSIF4PizeobMl6UM6kn9AMWw2BR6dQpSDH9RUBXtOMLMpYcM9QWREQ`

Corresponding public key

```
{
    "x": "q4fDFdZ7EYvvg9SAXk6rHLYV/PUBYqW75oZMGEDwGPA=",
    "y": "0A1aD+vcHB7X/H/75DiixSRLIMq4Tts1FHyEhpqZX1Q=",
    "algorithm": "ES256"
  },
```

ECDsa instance is generated as follows:

```
ECDsa.Create(new ECParameters
            {
                Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256,
                D = privKeyInt.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                Q = new ECPoint
                {
                    X = pubKeyX,
                    Y = pubKeyY
                }
            });
```

Comment: If anybody provides code that doesn't rely on a host of external libraries, then replicating the code would be "easy" right? What kind of "easy" are you looking for?

Comment: Right. Pseudo-code or non-C# code would work. (ideal is something like "you missed method ECDsa.GetPublicKeyInDerForJwtIo", but...)
 Just explanation of DER format for EC based on data I have would be ok too. Like "first 5 bytes - 'ES256', then 0x04 for uncompressed format of the key, then 32b of X, then 32b of Y, then [... this and that ...], all base64-encoded"